# javascript create object with attributes using getElementById

Tags: javascript, object, getelementbyid

I've built a simple practice game with 5 values stored separately. I want to put these 5 values/divs into a single object, but I'm confused about the output. the console.log returns: "the value for cardValue is [object HTMLDivElement]". The first part is working, but I'm confused about the latter. When I type into my console player.cardValue I get 'player is not defined'. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
  var cardValue = document.getElementById('cardValue');
  var cardValue2 = document.getElementById('cardValue2');
  var playerHit1Div = document.getElementById('playerHit1Div');
  var playerHit2Div = document.getElementById('playerHit2Div');
  var playerHit3Div = document.getElementById('playerHit3Div');


    var player = {
    cardValue: document.getElementById('cardValue'),
    cardValue2: document.getElementById('cardValue2'),
    playerHit1Div: document.getElementById('playerHit1Div'),
    playerHit2Div: document.getElementById('playerHit2Div'),
    playerHit3Div: document.getElementById('playerHit3Div')
  };

  for (var x in player){
    console.log('the value for ' + x + ' is ' + player[x]);
  }
```

Comment: You need help in what? Your code works as expected and you confirmed it.

Comment: When doing var prop in object is a good practice to add an if statement to check hasOwnProperty: you can see a reference in here

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: For example, I have text contained in the div 'cardValue', shouldn't the console.log return the text, not [object HTMLdivElement]?

Comment: @KM617, no, because you are collecting HTMLElement Objects. If you need the text of the element, you'll need to use `player[x].textContent`

Comment: No it should be [object HTMLdivElement], if you need text you should get the text value from the element, it could be a value or a text depends on the element

Comment: @KM617—a div is a host object, when you output it to the console, it may return whatever it wants.

Comment: you could use a polyfill to access properties, like jquery in order to access those values in the correct way.

Comment: You might get `player` is not defined in the console, if said variable it's not defined in the global scope (like inside a load handler)

Comment: @juangarcia—not only is there no specification for what a DOM object should output when passed to *console.log*, the *console.log* method isn't standardised. So what you see is whatever the developer of that particular implementation has decided you should see.

Comment: @RobG I agree with you, it is not standardised, but he wants the value or text of the DOM object, I recommend using a polyfill library like jquery or mootools or any other that could actually get the value this developer needs.

Comment: @juangarcia—there is no need at all for a library to read a property of a DOM object. The OP simply doesn't know which property to access. Adding a library to call a method to access a property will not solve that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, this makes more sense. One more question: why is it in my console I can't get a return value when typing 'player.cardValue'? shouldn't I be able to access the object doing this and at least get the same message: the value for cardValue is [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Is `player` a global variable?

Comment: @juan garcia that's good to know, I've been learning/working with jquery as well but am currently practicing JS

Comment: Then typing `player` into the console should work. I suspect you're wrong about it being a global variable, maybe it's inside a function like `window.onload = function() { blah }`

Comment: @barmar you're right, sorry it is within the window.onload, thank you

Comment: set a breakpoint after the `player` assignment, then you can work in the scope of the function.

Comment: @KM617 did you get your question answered? if not I will try to help with some samples.

Comment: @juan garcia I've followed at least in part what people are saying, but examples would be great! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the behaviour of the console. It's implementation dependent and has quite different behaviour in each browser that has one, so you need to learn the peculiarities of the one(s) you are using.

Running your code and entering `player.cardValue` into the console in IE returns:

```
player.cardValue
null
```

In Chrome it returns:

```
null
```

Which is expected as I don't have any element with an ID of *cardValue*. Note that if you do have suitable elements in the page, they must be *before* the code, otherwise when the code runs, the elements don't exist yet. Or you can run the code after the onload event (e.g. use `window.onload = function(){...}`)

If you wish to get the text content of an element, then use its *textContent* property. Older IE supports *innerText* instead, so you can do:

```
var theText = element.textContent || element.innerText;
```

If you want to get the markup inside the element, use its *innerHTML* property, which has been supported by all browsers for a long time:

```
var theMarkup = element.innerHTML;
```

To see reliable output, write your own output routines and don't rely on the console's interpretation of what you might want, at least until you are familiar with how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that console log has many cool features like error / debug / warn / info / assert, you can also profile and also trace. console.log has very cool features and is browser dependent as it was spoken in the comments.

If there is an element in DOM with id cardValue you will get in player.cardValue the Html Object that represents it, you will actually get the value or text of the DOM element depending on the kind of element it is.

For instance getting the text from an element could be some times innerText of the element and in other cases .value attribute of an input text and so on.

Accessing to those values depends on each case of the element you are trying to get info from. And not only that but actually also depends on the DOCTYPE you define, so it is good to have some kind of library to get access in the correct way to the values we need from DOM in the way we expect.

I will also add a reference a book I read, that explains that accessing with attr of jquery actually handles browser incompatibilities.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for this. I'll need to read/practice again but this definitely sheds some light, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help, hope you have a great time with js and something great with it